# Tilde Delimited to AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

Can we take a tilde delimited file and feed it to AS400 as is, or does the file need to be converted to fixed width?  I am told by the AS400 engineer that the file needs to be converted to fixed width.

The environment is made up of SQL Server 2005, Visual Studio 2005, and AS400. The tilde delimited file is given by an outside source as is. We are trying to take this file and get it to AS400 to process purchase orders.

Below is a sample of a file we need to feed into the AS400. Original thought was to convert to a format which SQL Server can read, break up into different tables by group, i.e. PROCESSPO, PO, and LINE, so we can properly define columns. Then create files, in this case 3, for the developer feed into the AS400. There will always be 5 different types of records but I am only providing 3 record types because this is all the data I am given to work with.

```
PROCESSPO~TP-4186~CARQUEST~ALLTRADE~1.2~2011-04-06T13:24:45.000-07:00  
PO~TP-4186~TP-4186~2011-04-06T13:24:45.000-07:00~TR-13824~TR-13824~1~0~RAL~Raleigh DC~2635 Millbrook Road~~~Raleigh~NC~27604~US~555-555-5555~177200~DCS Raleigh Store~2635 Millbrook Road~~~Raleigh~NC~27604~US~555-123-4567~  
LINE~TP-4186~1~TP-4186~430937~TLS~1.0~EA~FEDGRD~ALLT_LB~Alltrade Tools LLC~1431 Via Plata~~~Long Beach~CA~90810~US~310-522-9008~
```

Since I don't know AS400 I don't know how it will take in this data but I have spoken to different resources who say it can accept Excel spreadsheets but not sure how it will read the data because they have only worked with spreadsheets having set number of columns across the board. I also pinged the Stackoverflow community for this same reason.

AFTER SPEAKING WITH THE AS400 DEVELOPER IT WAS DECIDED THAT ONE FIXED WIDTH FILE WAS HIS IDEAL SOLUTION BUT THAT IT WAS NOT A REQUIREMENT, MORE OF A DESIRE THAN ANYTHING ELSE. I CREATED MULTIPLE FILES AND AM FEEDING THE DATA DIRECTLY INTO THE AS400 FROM VISUAL STUDIO 2005.  THANKS TO ALL FOR YOU FEEDBACK.

Comment: It would seem you already have your answer (or are you saying you want a second opinion).

Comment: I'm sure that a 400 developer could transform a tilde-delimited file if they had to but it's a heck of a lot easier using .Net's Replace() function.  IMHO, if you're writing an app that is serving as the middle-man between two systems, it makes sense that transforms should be done by your app.

Comment: @David Stratton:  Does .NET's replace() really know how to find the width of each field, and replace the tildes with the necessary number of spaces to pad out those fields?  If not, then I daresay it is easier to use the facilities already available on the AS/400.  If custom code does have to be written, then which platform is easier/quicker depends almost entirely the programmers and their familiarity with the available languages and tools.

Comment: @John Y.  True.  Sometimes I'm a bit bone-headed and simplistic.

Comment: That's a bit overly complicated.  Since you're using Visual Studio 2005 I assume you can do this in .NET.  This previous post shows how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654568/the-best-way-to-convert-delimited-to-fixed-width  Don't worry about the iSeries.  Worry about transforming from one format to another.  It shouldn't matter to you if the system on the other end is an iSeries, Windows, Linux, Federation, Ferengi, or Borg system.  You just need to do the transform as simply as possible.

Comment: @David: I agree that it is a bit complicated and I appreciate your feedback. The only question I have with this solution you are referring me to is if it can be applied to a file which will have different number of records each time as well as different number of fields per line, i.e. row 1 will have 6 fields and row 2 will have 29 fields? I have 3 VB resources and they all say it needs to be parsed by line but I will not have same number of records each time. My only gripe is that I think AS400 can take delimited files but don't know it enough to say.

Comment: Ah.  The solution I referred you to would not work on that out of the box. You would need to modify it slightly and perhaps throw in an if statement to handle each line based on the number of fields.  Either way, it requires coding and minimally complex logic from the sound of it.  Either way, it will likely take a developer.  As John Y pointed out, either an AS/400 or a .NET developer can do it, but if the AS/400 Engineer is telling you that you need to do it, and they are the authority, then it needs to be done.

Comment: Give me sample data and more clearly state what you are trying to do and I'll remove the down vote.

Comment: @Wence Can you edit the lines and use the code formatter so we can see each line individually? Or add four spaces before each line.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Completely changing answer to match new question.

As a single file, no the IBM i cannot deal with that file. An upload can only go into one table. As mentioned in another answer, you can upload 5 individual files for each record type, but why write a program to do that when your program can just parse everything and directly add it to the database. This program can be easily written in any language including RPG.

One thought, this looks like an EDI document. Is this true? If so, there are software packages that can automatically parse this and dump into tables. I am researching EDI myself right now.

Comment: These are good first-line options.  It is a no-brainer to at least give them a try.  I have found they can be insufficient, though (especially on older systems; I hear they have gotten better).

Comment: @Wence That would have been valuable information in the original question. The only thing you can do in that case is to write a parser. I am in a similar situation right now with an EDI document. I will have a write something to handle each line type differently.

Comment: @Wence Wait? You are writing a VB app to work with this? Just dump it directly in the tables that will receive the data to process and skip the CSV.

Comment: To directly answer your question. Yes, the IBM i can deal with CSV/tab delimited files. Each line must be for the same table and each column must be of the same data type. If each line can be different, a program must be written to break apart the lines and manually add them to the correct location. If you are processing in VB, just write it directly to the tables on the IBM i.

Comment: I've not written any VB to parse lines before so that will be a challenge. I mean how would I state the IFTHEN statement to define not just range but data type and field length?

Comment: I think you are making this more complicated than it is. You can use ODBC, OLE DB, or IBM's ADO.NET data provider and then do SQL inserts into the correct table(s).

Comment: In c# I believe it is something like `string[] result = fileString.Split("~")`. This is a real basic version, but it is a start. I would guess that VB has something similar.

Comment: @Wence Are you not listening? IIRC, you said that there a different formats in the file. The import tool assumes the entire file is for one table. **It can't do multiple tables**. Now if your goal is to just dump the data into a flat file on the IBM i, you can do that. But a program is still needed to process the file. Give us some sample data so we can help you further. Until I see the data, I am done helping.

Comment: @Wence I do apologize for being somewhat of a jerk. I want to help, but I was missing part of the picture that you have added. I hope this helps more.

Comment: The file could be uploaded as is to the server (AS400) and an experienced RPG programmer could process it any way it needs to be done. The file could be written into a flat file in the library file system or written as a streamfile in the /root file system. RPG can read it and process it either way. Or RPG could read it from a shared directory from a Windows server somewhere out in the Windows network; the file doesn't need to be "uploaded" at all as long as a network path is available.

Answer (score 2):

An AS400 can handle a tilde-delimited file, but only if the AS400 programmer wrote the code to do so.  I think your AS400 engineer is really telling you that they have no intention of modifying their code to accommodate tilde-delimitation, so it's up to you to translate the file into a fixed-width format.

Comment: Nice.  You posted that just as I was putting my comment in above.  That's pretty much what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm watching the stream of comments accumulating under Mike Wills's answer and thinking that Stack Overflow, cool as it is, is probably not the best medium for that conversation. ;)

Still, data interfacing is one of those tasks that is pretty much always achievable, so it would be nice to get closer to a solution here.  (I expect to edit this answer if it too starts to collect comments.)

*[Edit: Making use of additional comments and sample data added to original question]*

Since it looks like your various records are incompatible formats, I would go with your proposed plan of splitting the received tilde-delimited input into separate tables or files, one for each record type.  Then it should be easy enough to get that data into the AS/400.

At this point, I'm not sure what the exact problem is.  It was good that you added so much information to your question, and your basic approach seems sound to me.  If you can give more specifics about what your AS/400 person needs from you, that might be helpful.  (For example, are there already appropriate files on the AS/400 that are ready to accept the data?)

Comment: Yes, I should add more info to my answer based on the comment thread. What @Wence asked and what he was trying to do were two completely different things. @Wence, please update the question with more details, perhaps some examples of the raw data. Our answer will probably be the same, but we can clarify our answers to match your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the FTP server on an AS400 is really smart and can convert incoming flat files into AS/400 records as part of the FTP upload process.

I would therefore suggest investigating a conversion of the tilde-delimited file to a form understood by the FTP server (probably by replacing tilde with tabs).